# Error when trying to create list with a specific range. Why?

Tags: python, arrays, list

```
numbers=list(range(10))
print(numbers)
```

Gives the following error:

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Can someone explain to me why I'm getting this error, please?

Comment: I guess somewhere else in your code, you defined a variable like `list = [1, 2, 3]`

Comment: I agree. Here is a pastebin to show you what you probably did and the matching error: http://pastebin.com/t57Ut43D

Comment: Or, Alternatively, `print = [1,2,3]`

Comment: @ppperry Or maybe `range = [1, 2, 3]`. ^^